# What does "&" mean in latex?

Tags: symbols

I am using the align command to align equations :

```
\begin{align*}
  \psi \colon & SU(2)\otimes SU(2) \otimes SU(2) \to  \mathbb{C}\\
  &(U_{l_1} \otimes U_{l_2} \otimes U_{l_3})  \mapsto  \psi(U_{l_1} \otimes U_{l_2} \otimes U_{l_3}).
\end{align*}
```

As I understand it, the "&" tells to latex where the object need to be vertically aligned.

But does & mean something in general in latex ? Or is it a command that has always different significations ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default, `&` is exactly the alignment character, and even has its own category code (4). It is defined this way in both TeX and LaTeX.  For more on category codes see [What are category codes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16410/2693).

As with almost everything in TeX, it could in principle be reassigned to do something else, but usually it is not. TikZ in fact *does* reassign it, because in  TikZ matrix contexts it means `\pgfmatrixnextcell`, but this is a special case.

So for the most part, yes, `&` is the alignment character used in tabular material and other alignment structures like `align` and `array`, etc.

For more discussion on why `&` is always special even outside of these environments see:

- [Why is & special outside of tabular environments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/313457/2693)